# jquery body on hover cannot target other DIVS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scope

I am trying to access my own javascript function from within a:

```
$("body").on("mouseenter",".noteNode",function(){});
```

The trouble seems to be that when I am inside the function above jQuery will not allow me to get access to other elements?

Let me elaborate further:
Actual code I want to use I've jsfiddled: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ2Yb/8/

I believe the function is being called as I had wanted it to be, but as you can see $(this) is not able to target the actual div which is being hovered, and so when trying to pass this data to the other function it just doesn't arrive - why is this? I believe it's a scope problem but I have tried a few ways to solve it and searched S.O without much luck yet.

The reason I **need** to use $("body").on is because I am creating the DIV's (which will be hovered) on the fly with JS.

As you can see the hover function is working fine and firing as it should do, but totally unable to access anything in the DOM which I don't understand

.

**[Edit]** so to clarify: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ2Yb/8/

I am trying to pass the ID of the DIV (which was created BY JS) over to my own function in which i want to try and access the DIVs offset parameter - but i am unable to do so, you will see in my revised fiddle that i am just getting 'undefined' in my alert box which is not what i wanted - i am still convinced that this is because of a scope issue.

Comment: `<div class="noteNode">Note Node</div>` no id assigned to the div. It's working as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/uJ2Yb/3/

Comment: `ID` is not assigned to your divs :)

Comment: [A fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/uJ2Yb/6/) - with ID's

Comment: my question is wrong i ended up over simplifying my issue... should i edit or should i create a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/uJ2Yb/7/

```
function myFunction(someVar){ alert(someVar); } 

$("body").on("mouseenter",".noteNode",function(event){
    myFunction(event.target.innerHTML );
    //alert( event.target.innerHTML );
});
```

Comment: I used your code and managed to work it into this: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ2Yb/9/ which is what i wanted - so event.target is what i needed - and i presume that's because you're passing it into the function call from jQuery - whereas in mine http://jsfiddle.net/uJ2Yb/8/ i am not

Comment: I've accepted this, because even with my updated question it fits the bill, basically I should have been passing the event to the function call instead of leaving it anonymous (if thats the right phrasing!)

Answer (score 0):

Please Assign Unique Id To Your Divs

try This Code

```
function myFunction(someVar){ alert(someVar); } 

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").append('<div class="noteNode" id="a">Note Node</div>');
   $("body").append('<div class="noteNode" id="b">Note Node</div>');
   $("body").append('<div class="noteNode" id="c">Note Node</div>');
});


$("body").on("mouseenter",".noteNode",function(){
    myFunction( $(this).attr("id") );
    alert( $(this).attr("id") );
});
```